# Default parameter value must be a compile-time constant error message

Tags: c#, webforms, compiler-errors

I seem to get an error message like the one i mentioned in the title. 
"Default parameter value for 'randomizer' must be a compile-time constant error message."

For this code:

```
    public Random Randomizer {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public ShuffleDeck( Random randomizer = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond)) {
            this.Randomizer = randomizer;
        }
```

and I cant figure out why? Anyone have any clues?

Comment: I'd say the error message is pretty clear.  It's a pretty darn big clue.  The default value you are providing is not a compile time constant.  It needs to be a compile time constant.

Comment: On a side note, there's no real reason to see the `Random` with the current millisecond.  By default it will be seeded with the current tick count, which has a lot more entropy to it than `Millisecond` does.  As it stands, your random number generator only has 1000 possible sequences that it can generate, which is way less than it's capable of.

Answer (score 4):

> and I cant figure out why?

Well thats what the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) for the language say.

> A default value must be one of the following types of expressions:
>
> - **a constant expression;**
> - an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value    type, such as an enum or a struct;
> - an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value    type.

You can do *(but see [Servy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969857/default-parameter-value-must-be-a-compile-time-constant-error-message/22969914#comment35073940_22969914))*:

```
public ShuffleDeck(Random randomizer = null) {
    if (randomizer == null)
        this.Randomizer = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    else
        this.Randomizer = randomizer;
   //or this.Randomizer = randomizer ?? new Random());
}
```

Or you can have overload constructors like:

```
public ShuffleDeck()
    : this(new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond))
{
}
public ShuffleDeck(Random randomizer)
{
    this.Randomizer = randomizer;
}
```

Comment: Using `null` as the default value may be okay here, but in the general case it's not always an option, if in context `null` is a sensible real value to be used.  Here it plausibly isn't useful, so it's acceptable to always transform it into the default value.  Also note the null coalesce operator will simply the syntax.

Comment: You can also add `this.Randomizer = randomizer ?? new Random());` to your list of ways to accomplish this.

Comment: @Pixelfish, yeah that is what Servy pointed out in his comment as well, thanks added to the answer